# Updating view controller from server call best practice

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I'm quite new to server calls and MVC architecture in general. I imagine this is a silly question.

I have a variable in my model, pressedUsers, and I'm unsure the appropriate way to communicate to my view when it's been updated.

When my  class: UserPage property: userID is set it goes to a database and returns a stored array of other users.

```
class UserPage {

private var pressedUsers = [String]()
var userID: String? = nil {
    didSet{
        getPressedUsersFromServer()
    }
}

 private func getPressedUsersFromServer(){
    if(userID != nil){
        let docRef = db.collection("users").document(userID!)
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                if let dbPressedUsers = document.get("matchedUsers") as? [String] {
                    print("found")
                    self.pressedUsers = dbPressedUsers
                }
            }
        }

        }
}
```

}

If the model updates its view immediately after assigning a userID because of the delay from the server call the information from pressed users isn't displayed. I could pass the VC to UserPage directly and use that to update the View after the information is obtained but that seems to undermine what I understand about MVC.

My (poor) understanding is that maybe the right way to do this to implement a protocol and create a delegate property within the UserPage class? something like

```
protocol matchedUserDelegate{
   func pressedUsersUpdate(_ sender: UserPage) 
}
```

and add a property in the UserPage?

```
var delegate: pressedUserDelegate?
var private var pressedUsers = [String]() {
        didSet{
            delegate.pressedUsersUpdate()
        }
    }
```

And handle the update in pressedUsersUpdate within the view controller?
Is there better practice for something like this?

Comment: Another option would be to use the Notification Center but in my opinion using the Protocol Delegate Pattern is the better option.

Comment: why didn't you use completion handler instead of delegate?

Comment: I actually think using a completion handler is better than using the delegate pattern. Seems like unnecessary over-engineering

Comment: It looks like a completion handler is the simpler way to be handling this, thanks guys!